# Ingesting Project Assets With Service Account Via Manifest (NodeJs)

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm using a service account to connect to Earth Engine API and attempting to ingest some assets from Google cloud Storage using a manifest:

```
uploadManifest: any = {
    id: `project/martynsproject/assets/${item_id]}`,
    tilesets: [{
        sources: [{
            primaryPath: gsFilePath
        }]
    }],
    pyramidingPolicy: "MEAN",
    properties: {
        ...metadata.properties,
        "system:time_start": aquired.valueOf(),
    }
};
           
ee.data.newTaskId(1, (taskIds) => {
    ee.data.startIngestion(taskIds[0], uploadManifest, async (result, error) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`Ingestion request failed`, error);
        } else {
            var assetId = uploadManifest.id;
            var taskId = result.taskId;
            console.log(`Ingestion Task for file [${gsFilePath}] started. Destination [${assetId}]`);
        }
    });
});
```

The ingestion task is started successfully, however when I later check the status of the task it has failed with an error:

> Asset 'projects/martynsproject/assets' does not exist or doesn't allow this operation.

I'm sure this is because the `projects/martynsproject/assets` folder doesn't exist, but how do I create this and give appropriate permissions on it for myself and the service account to access it?

*Please note the name of our project is not actually `martynsproject`, I have just changed it for privacy reasons.